# Application Warmup not working

Tags: iis-7, startup

We have an application which, on startup, populates it's cache from an csv. This takes about 1 minute. We thought putting an application warm up on it would eliviate the problem, but it seems like the requests specified are not being executed. Hitting the application locally will take a minute and then be instant thereafter. I tried several requests, relative (to localhost and application root) and absolute ones, to no avail. It does not work after stop/starting the corresponding app pool, nor recyclying (if there is a difference to application warm up), nor rebuilding the application.

Anyone have suggestions I could try?

Edit: The event viewer does not have anything related to the application warm up (as far as I can tell) and Application_start() is not called

Answer (score 0):

if you're not seeing warmup requests in your logs perhaps you don't have them enabled in your application settings? What language are you using? (Warmup requests are enabled by default for all Java applications.)
I see entries for /_ah/warmup in my logs.